# Spring Boot WSDL SOAP web service application does not start

Tags: spring-boot, web-services, soap, wsdl, jax-ws

**I am trying to start a WSDL-SOAP web service application but it doesn't start. Gives the below exception:**

```
2020-11-30 22:28:12.521  INFO 97564 --- [           main] c.c.ws.soap.SpringBootApplicationRun     : Starting SpringBootApplicationRun on Ramazans-MacBook-Pro.local with PID 97564 (started by rdemir in /Users/rdemir/Projects/METU/SM704/Project Phase 2)
2020-11-30 22:28:12.525  INFO 97564 --- [           main] c.c.ws.soap.SpringBootApplicationRun     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-11-30 22:28:13.304  INFO 97564 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6d2d075b] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-11-30 22:28:13.330  INFO 97564 --- [           main] .w.s.a.s.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping : Supporting [WS-Addressing August 2004, WS-Addressing 1.0]
2020-11-30 22:28:13.597  INFO 97564 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-11-30 22:28:13.623  INFO 97564 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-11-30 22:28:13.623  INFO 97564 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.13
2020-11-30 22:28:13.639  INFO 97564 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/Users/rdemir/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.]
2020-11-30 22:28:13.757  INFO 97564 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/wsdlfirstws]   : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-11-30 22:28:13.758  INFO 97564 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1165 ms
2020-11-30 22:28:14.064  INFO 97564 --- [           main] o.a.c.w.s.f.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean : Creating Service {http://soap.ws.ckranz.com/}BankingServiceImplementationService from class com.banking.BankingPortType
2020-11-30 22:28:14.145  WARN 97564 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'endpoint' defined in class path resource [com/ckranz/ws/soap/config/WebServiceConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.xml.ws.Endpoint]: Factory method 'endpoint' threw exception; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
2020-11-30 22:28:14.148  INFO 97564 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-11-30 22:28:14.158  INFO 97564 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-11-30 22:28:14.164 ERROR 97564 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'endpoint' defined in class path resource [com/ckranz/ws/soap/config/WebServiceConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.xml.ws.Endpoint]: Factory method 'endpoint' threw exception; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
```

**Here is some code:**

https://www.codepile.net/pile/Ym773bm2

Comment: it would help if you post code here?

Comment: @priyranjan I updated with a code link